# Add and edit items in sap.m.table

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I have a problem. I bind oData service to this table and it has functions (Add, Edit, Save and Cancel).

[image]

So I'm able to add new rows by clicking the + button, which will trigger the  `onAddViewTaskItem()` (code provided below).

[image]

So I input new description and sub description for the new item. However, if I edit any current items (not the new created ones), it will trigger `updateItems()` in `ListBase` object which calls `updateAggregation`.

As I debug, it updates with the current binding contexts (which I see there only 3 items in contexts instead of 4). It seems that when I `addItem` to the table, it doesn't add the new created context to the table's binding context.

Is there anyway to update the binding context?

```
onAddViewTaskItem: function(oEvent) {
    this.getModel("viewSettings").setProperty("/visible", true);
    this.getModel("viewSettings").setProperty("/editable", true);
    this._createAddRow();
  },
  _createAddRow: function() {
    var _oContext = this._createTaskItemContext();
    this._addTableRow(_oContext);
  },
  _createTaskItemContext: function(oEvent) {
    return this.getModel("xsodata").createEntry("/TaskItems", {
      properties: {
        "TaskItemID": this._generateGuid(),
        "YearID": this._oScheduleDetailDialog.getBindingContext("xsodata").getObject().YearID,
        "TaskDescription": "",
        "TaskSubDescription": "",
        "DeleteFlag": ""
      },
      success: function(oEvent) {}.bind(this),
      error: function(oEvent) {}.bind(this)
    });
  },
  _addTableRow: function(oContext) {
    var oScheduleTaskItem = this._createRowControls();
    this.getView().addDependent(oScheduleTaskItem);
    oScheduleTaskItem.setBindingContext(oContext, "xsodata");
    this.byId("tblScheduleItems").addItem(oScheduleTaskItem);
  },
  _createRowControls: function(oComboBoxControl) {
    return new ColumnListItem({
      cells: [
        this._createInputControl("viewSettings>/editable", "i18n>description", "xsodata>TaskDescription"),
        this._createInputControl("viewSettings>/editable", "i18n>subDescription", "xsodata>TaskSubDescription"),
        this._createCheckboxControl("viewSettings>/editable", "xsodata>DeleteFlag")
      ]
    });
  },
  _createInputControl: function(sEditable, sPlaceholder, sBindingProperty) {
    var _oInputControl = new Input({
      maxLength: 255,
      editable: "{" + sEditable + "}",
      placeholder: "{" + sPlaceholder + "}",
      value: "{" + sBindingProperty + "}"
    });
    return _oInputControl;
  },
  _createCheckboxControl: function(sEditable, sBindingProperty) {
    var _oCheckBoxControl = new CheckBox({
      editable: "{" + sEditable + "}",
      selected: "{= ${" + sBindingProperty + "} === 'X' ? true : false}",
      select: this.handleDeleteFlagSelect
    });
    return _oCheckBoxControl;
  },
  handleDeleteFlagSelect: function(oEvent) {
    var bSelected = oEvent.getParameter("selected");
    var sPath = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("xsodata").getPath();
    this.getModel("xsodata").setProperty(sPath + "/DeleteFlag", bSelected ? "X" : "");
  },
```